# SwapBuffers() not recognized

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl

Can someone help me with why I am unable to use SwapBuffers()?
I am using WindowsForms c# with OpenTK in Visual Studio 2015. I am using the HelloGL3_OpenTK code to learn from. Everything else seems okay, but the SwapBuffers() line. I get a message :
**The name SwapBuffers does not occur in the current context.**
I really would like to understand what's wrong, so I hope someone can help.

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Platform;

namespace Draw3Dv01wf
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // vertex shader
        string vertexShaderSource = @"
#version 140

precision highp float;

uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;

in vec3 in_position;
in vec3 in_normal;

out vec3 normal;

void main(void)
{
    //works only for orthogonal modelview
    normal = (modelview_matrix * vec4(in_normal, 0)).xyz;

    gl_Position = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * vec4(in_position, 1);
}";

        // fragment shader
        string fragmentShaderSource = @"
#version 140

precision highp float;

const vec3 ambient = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
const vec3 lightVecNormalized = normalize(vec3(0.5, 0.5, 2.0));
const vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.9, 0.9, 0.7);

in vec3 normal;

out vec4 out_frag_color;

void main(void)
{
  float diffuse = clamp(dot(lightVecNormalized, normalize(normal)), 0.0, 1.0);
  out_frag_color = vec4(ambient + diffuse * lightColor, 1.0);
}";

        int vertexShaderHandle,
            fragmentShaderHandle,
            shaderProgramHandle,
            modelviewMatrixLocation,
            projectionMatrixLocation,
            vaoHandle,
            positionVboHandle,
            normalVboHandle,
            eboHandle;

        Vector3[] positionVboData = new Vector3[]{
            new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),
            new Vector3( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),
            new Vector3( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),
            new Vector3(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),
            new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
            new Vector3( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
            new Vector3( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f),
            new Vector3(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f) };

        int[] indicesVboData = new int[]{
             // front face
                0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
                // top face
                3, 2, 6, 6, 7, 3,
                // back face
                7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7,
                // left face
                4, 0, 3, 3, 7, 4,
                // bottom face
                0, 1, 5, 5, 4, 0,
                // right face
                1, 5, 6, 6, 2, 1, };

        Matrix4 projectionMatrix, modelviewMatrix;

        public Form1()
        {
            // required method for designer support
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // load event handler
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateShaders();
            CreateVBOs();
            CreateVAOs();

            // set color
            GL.ClearColor(System.Drawing.Color.MidnightBlue);
            // enable or disable server-side capabilities
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        }

        // render frame event handler
        private void Form1_Render(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set viewport
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);

            // bind vertex array object
            GL.BindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

            // render primatives from array data
            GL.DrawElements(
                PrimitiveType.Triangles,    // kind of primative ****
                indicesVboData.Length,      // number of elements
                DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt,   /* type of values in the 
            indices - must be UnsignedByte|Short|int */
                IntPtr.Zero); /* pointer to location where the 
            indicies are stored */

            // clear frame (to be drawn) and depth buffer
            GL.Clear(
                ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | 
                ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            //**************** SwapBuffers() not recognized ******//
SwapBuffers()
        }

        // update frame event handler
        private void Form1_Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Matrix4 rotation = 
            //    Matrix4.CreateRotationY((float)e.Time);
            //Matrix4.Mult(
            //    ref rotation, ref modelviewMatrix, out modelviewMatrix);
            //GL.UniformMatrix4(
            //    modelviewMatrixLocation, false, ref modelviewMatrix);

            //var keyboard = OpenTK.Input.Keyboard.GetState();
            //if (keyboard[OpenTK.Input.Key.Escape])
            //{
            //    Exit();
            //}
        }

        //private void SwapBuffers()
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}

        private void CreateShaders()
        {
            // create shader object
            vertexShaderHandle = 
                GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
            fragmentShaderHandle = 
                GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);

            GL.ShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShaderSource);
            GL.ShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShaderSource);

            // compile shader object
            GL.CompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
            GL.CompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

            Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderHandle));
            Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderHandle));

            // Create program
            shaderProgramHandle = GL.CreateProgram();

            // attach shader object to the program object
            GL.AttachShader(shaderProgramHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
            GL.AttachShader(shaderProgramHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

            /* associate a generic vertex attribute index with 
             a named attribute variable */
            GL.BindAttribLocation(
                shaderProgramHandle, // handle of the program object
                0, // index of the generic vertex attribute to bind
                "in_position"); /* string containing name of 
            vertex shader attribute variable to bind */
            GL.BindAttribLocation(shaderProgramHandle, 1, "in_normal");

            // link program object
            GL.LinkProgram(shaderProgramHandle);
            Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramHandle));
            // installs program object as part of current rendering state
            GL.UseProgram(shaderProgramHandle);

            // Set uniforms
            projectionMatrixLocation = 
                // location of uniform variable
                GL.GetUniformLocation(
                    shaderProgramHandle, "projection_matrix");
            modelviewMatrixLocation =
                GL.GetUniformLocation(
                    shaderProgramHandle, "modelview_matrix");

            float aspectRatio = // aspect ratio - width / height
                ClientSize.Width / (float)(ClientSize.Height);
            // create a perspective projection matrix
            Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                (float)Math.PI / 4, // angle of fov in y direction
                aspectRatio, // aspect ratio of view (width/height)
                1, // distance to the near clip plane
                100, // distance to the far clip plane
                out projectionMatrix); /* projection matrix which
                transforms camera space to raster space */

            modelviewMatrix = 
                // build a world spacve to camera space matrix
                Matrix4.LookAt(
                    new Vector3(0, 3, 5),   // eye 
                    new Vector3(0, 0, 0),   // target
                    new Vector3(0, 1, 0));  // up

            GL.UniformMatrix4(
                projectionMatrixLocation,   // location
                false,                      // transpose
                ref projectionMatrix);      // matrix
            GL.UniformMatrix4(
                modelviewMatrixLocation, false, ref modelviewMatrix);
        }

        private void CreateVBOs()
        {
            positionVboHandle = GL.GenBuffer(); // buffer object names
            // bind named buffer object 
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, positionVboHandle);
            // create and initiatize buffer object's data store
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, // target buffer object 
                new IntPtr(positionVboData.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                    /* size in bytes of buffer object' new data store */
                positionVboData, /* pointer to the data that will be 
            copied into the data store */
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw); /* the expected usage 
            pattern of the data store */

            normalVboHandle = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, normalVboHandle);
            GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                new IntPtr(positionVboData.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                positionVboData, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            eboHandle = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, eboHandle);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer,
                new IntPtr(sizeof(uint) * indicesVboData.Length),
                indicesVboData, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            // bind named buffer object (buffer target, buffer name)
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        private void CreateVAOs()
        {
            /* GL3 allows us to store the vertex layout in a 
             * "vertex array object" (VAO). 
             * This means that we don't have to re-issue 
             * VertexAttribPointer calls every time we try to use a 
             * different vertex layout - these calls are stored in 
             * the VAO so we simply need to bind the correct VAO. */
            vaoHandle = GL.GenVertexArray();
            GL.BindVertexArray(vaoHandle); // bind vertex array object

            // enable vertex attribute array 
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0); 
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, positionVboHandle);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(
                0, // index
                3, // size
                VertexAttribPointerType.Float, // type
                true, // normalized 
                Vector3.SizeInBytes, // stride
                0); // offset

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, normalVboHandle);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(
                1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, 
                true, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

            // bind buffer
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, eboHandle);
            // bind vertex array object
            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have that method commented out in your code.

Comment: I put that there so as to highlight the place where I'm getting the problem. Sorry I forgot the semicolon. Should be  //**************** SwapBuffers() not recognized ******//
SwapBuffers(); My code just has SwapBuffers();

Comment: Oh, the method (sorry, my mistake) shouldn't be necessary. It's not in any examples I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that first problem is that you are missing ;

```
SwapBuffers();
```

As far as I know, you have to derive your class from **OpenTK.GameWindow** class, where

```
this.SwapBuffers();
```

is defined.

---

to the previous answer:
I didn't realised you do not use windows SwapBuffers(HDC hdc) function described in the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369060(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you explain the reason why? What is the difference?

Comment: Actually, I just discovered the answer while working on a fresh project, when I  tried to use GL.ClearColor before the OpenGL context. You're right. - I have not created a GL window context. I have to totally change this code though, since I am using windows forms, and I learned that I should use the gl.control alongside for what I am attempting. Thanks for your response.